# U-SQL job does not access Azure SQL Database

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-lake, u-sql

I was trying to retrieve data from Azure SQL Database using Azure Data Lake analytics by following [this](http://eatcodelive.com/2015/11/21/querying-azure-sql-database-from-an-azure-data-lake-analytics-u-sql-script/) guide. I run U-SQL job on Azure Data Lake analytics and got following error:

> Failed to connect to data source: 'SampleSource', with error(s):
>   'Cannot open server '' requested by the login. Client with
>   IP address '25.66.9.211' is not allowed to access the server.  To
>   enable access, use the Windows Azure Management Portal or run
>   sp_set_firewall_rule on the master database to create a firewall rule
>   for this IP address or address range.  It may take up to five minutes
>   for this change to take effect.'

After running my job couple of times, I observed IP range that needs to be added in server is pretty wide. It seems we need to add 25.66.xxx.xxx. I have two questions:

1. How can we narrow this range?
2. Why the typical setting that allows all azure services access doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

At this point you will have to add the full range (which are all internal IPs). The reason the typical setting is not working, is that the machines needing access are not managed in the same way. We are working on having them added. What data center is the database in?

Comment: This is some external database and I have read only access to it. I don't know about the location of the data center. For the time being, I have used data factory to move data to ADLS.

Comment: Thanks... It looks like that the whitelisting may have gotten dropped by the Azure SQL DB. We are working on getting it back.